# How to get Bootstrap 3 and Semantic:ui working together with meteor

Tags: meteor

Did somebody manage to get semantic:ui and Bootstrap 3 working together with meteor?

I am fairly new as an active member to Stackoverflow, so please forgive mistakes - should there be any -.

I am currently building a webpage with meteor - so far using mostly bootstrap 3 - (https://atmospherejs.com/nemo64/bootstrap). I just very recently stumbled over Semantic:UI (https://atmospherejs.com/semantic/ui) and have to say I love the UI Elements. I would now very much like to mix Semantic and Bootstrap. However, already the installation of Semantic seems to be impossible with bootstrap already being installed. For bootstrap one needs less (search for less on atmosphere) for semantic:UI one needs (search for flemay:less-autoprefixer). When having less and less-autoprefixer they fight over who gets to import stuff when starting meteor, so that doesn't work.

```
While building the application:    
error: conflict: two packages included in the app, less and flemay:less-autoprefixer, are both trying to handle .import.less    
error: conflict: two packages included in the app, less and flemay:less-autoprefixer, are both trying to handle .less
```

So I did what everybody would have done and removed the less package. Starting up meteor works then and also the .custom.semantic.json file gets created. There a new error occurs, one that I can not for the hell of it figure out:

```
W20150827-23:43:28.570(2)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
W20150827-23:43:28.570(2)? (STDERR)     at app/definitions/behaviors/api.js:1122:5
W20150827-23:43:28.570(2)? (STDERR)     at app/definitions/behaviors/api.js:1124:3 
W20150827-23:43:28.570(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/FBosler/Desktop/GetBuzzy/code/getbuzzy-web/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150827-23:43:28.570(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150827-23:43:28.570(2)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/FBosler/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.1vzxc70++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
```

Now adding less and removing flemay:less-autoprefixer yields another error:

```
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Errors prevented startup:                  
While building the application:    theme.import.less:20:10: Less compiler error: expected ')' got 'o'
```

Kinda lost here. Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for running both Bootstrap and Semantic UI - the mistake you mentioned won't show up if you just use `flemay:less-autoprefixer` instead of `less` package. Less-autoprefixer can manage both Semantic UI and Bootstrap, while less package will fail with Semantic UI.

`ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` occurs because you placed your custom.semantic.json or custom.bootstrap.json in a directory where it tries to run Semantic UI js files before initializing JQuery. You can see that the error is called by js files inside of definitions/behaviors path of your Semantic UI folder - these files try to use JQuery which wasn't initialized yet.

Put your Semantic UI and Bootstrap files into client/ directory and give it a second try.

Comment: You are right. flemay:less-autoprefixer works for both. The second error arose because I put the custom.semantic.json in my Rootdirectory, tehrefore meteor was trying to run it on the server also, there however is no jquery.
Eventually I got both of them working, but naming conflicts make simultaneous use almost impossible. I am now reverting back to the meteor only selector.